# How to add custom shortcuts to the PowerToys Run utility?

Tags: windows-10, shortcuts, powertoys

PowerToys Run utility makes a really great job enabling me to search and quickly open apps or folders.

However, is there a way to make my own custom shorcuts for apps/files/folders that I will use a lot, with shortened names/commands? I would like to give it a folder with shortcuts like this, for example:

[image: Folder with Windows shortcuts as short abbreviations]

So that I could open Notepad++ like this:

[image: PowerToys Run usage example]

Or would you rather suggest some other program to make this?
Thanks!

Comment: This is something I also wish to be able to do in PowerToys Run. Preferably like Launchbar for macOS, where you can add your own abbreviations for chosen files and folders.

Answer (score 3):

There's now a simpler method:

1. Close Powertoys
2. Open `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\PowerToys\PowerToys Run\Settings\Plugins\Microsoft.Plugin.Program\ProgramPluginSettings.json` with a file editor.
3. Add a program source to the content, the UID is anything you want:

```json
{
  "LastIndexTime": "2022-11-21T00:00:00+01:00",
  "ProgramSources": [
    {
      "Location": "C:\\Users\\{{username}}\\Documents\\Custom Shortcuts",
      "Name": "Custom Shortcuts",
      "Enabled": true,
      "UniqueIdentifier": "d379c7a9-bcfc-4edf-86b8-a256222558c2"
    }
  ],
  "DisabledProgramSources": [],
  "ProgramSuffixes": [
    "bat",
    "appref-ms",
    "exe",
    "lnk",
    "url"
  ],
  "EnableStartMenuSource": true,
  "EnableDesktopSource": true,
  "EnableRegistrySource": true,
  "EnablePathEnvironmentVariableSource": true,
  "MinScoreThreshold": 0.75
}
```

4. Save the file
5. In the `"Location"` you specified in the file, add the `.lnk` files you need
6. Open PowerToys and the shortcuts should appear now.

[image]

---

Source:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/3600#issuecomment-1321873022

Comment: This the way! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can 1.

create custom .lnk file, with command you need.
for example, I made .lnk files with these two:

`C:\Windows\System32\rasdial.exe "vpn name"` as vpn_on

and

`C:\Windows\System32\rasdial.exe "vpn name" /disconnect` as vpn_ff

2. Put these .lnk files to your Start directory, like a:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the shortcuts are placed in an indexed location, PowerRun should be able to display them. For instance, the following folders are included in Windows Search Index by default:

- C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

If you have many custom shortcuts in a folder, you can instead add (include) the folder to Indexing Options.